# Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Id_registro' at row 1 0.109 sec

Tags: mysql, csv

Tengo la tabla "registro" definida así en mi base de datos:

```sql
create table registro( 
    Id_registro int not null auto_increment, 
    fecha date, 
    financiero int not null, 
    clientes int not null, 
    procesos_internos int not null, 
    aprendizaje_desarrollo int not null, 
    observaciones varchar(45), 
    primary key(Id_registro) 
);
```

Y en un fichero .csv tengo los siguientes datos:

```
1,5/24/2016, 69 , 69 , 83 , 73 ,Hubo muy pocas ventas ese dia
```

Cuando intento realizar una inserción desde el fichero .csv obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'Id_registro' at row 1    0.109 sec

¿Por qué me sale este error? Si según yo declaré bien  mis variables. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por favor, añade más información como qué haces para que te dé este error

Comment: Hola mira yo necesito importar datos de un archivo .csv y pongo estas instrucciones:load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Libro1.csv" INTO TABLE registro;
FIElds TERMINATED by ',' y cuando ejecuto las intrucciones me sale ese error
lines terminated by '\n';

Comment: Tambien te sugiero que verifiques la configuración regional, dado que si usas separadores de decimal usando comas en vez de punto puede darte ese error

Answer (score 2):

Ese error ocurre porque intentas insertar un valor de tamaño mayor al permitido en el campo (por ejemplo, la cadena 'PRUEBA' que tiene 6 caracteres en un campo `CHAR(5)`).

Te recomendaría que abrieses el fichero .csv con un editor de texto o con Excel y que verificases que los valores de las columnas se ajustan a los valores de las columnas en la tabla destino en la base de datos.

Comment: De hecho el .csv viene de un archivo de excel y es una columa con una simple numeración, y esta de tipo numero y mi variable en mysql la tengo declarada como: Id_registro int not null auto_increment,

Comment: @TeresaCastro ¿Podrías añadir a la pregunta la estructura de la tabla (al menos la del campo Id_registro) y la fila con los datos que fallan en el csv (al menos la de la columna que irá a Id_registro)? Y sería mejor que lo hicieras desde un editor de texto, porque Excel formatea el fichero y no se ven los valores exactamente igual que en el contenido del csv

Comment: create table registro(
Id_registro int not null auto_increment,
fecha date,
financiero int not null,
clientes int not null,
procesos_internos int not null,
aprendizaje_desarrollo int not null,
observaciones varchar(45),
primary key(Id_registro)
);                                                                                                                y este es el archivo .csv                                                                                                                   1,5/24/2016, 69 , 69 , 83 , 73 ,Hubo muy pocas ventas ese dia

Comment: @TeresaCastro abre el csv con notepad y copia la primera fila aquí. Lo que has copiado viene de Excel y tiene un formato diferente al que tiene realmente en el fichero .csv

Comment: 1,5/24/2016, 69 , 69 , 83 , 73 ,Hubo muy pocas ventas ese dia                                                                                                                  el anterior lo copie del bloc de notas tambien

Comment: OK. Tenía la esperanza de que hubiera unas comillas ahí que fastidiaran el insert, pero no. ¿Tiene más filas el csv?¿tiene cabecera?

Comment: no tiene cabecera es solo una linea de datos precisamente para solo insertarlos en la base de datos, de hecho ya lo habia intentado y corria, pero los datos los cambie porque los necesitaba de otra forma y ya no corrio y me sigue saliendo ese error

Comment: @TeresaCastro La gracia es que cuando intento ejecutar los datos en local, recibo el fallo que mencionas... pero no para Id_registro, sino para fecha, porque el formato (5/24/2016) no le gusta. Si cambio la fecha a 2016-05-24, me funciona sin problemas ni mensajes de aviso/error

Comment: es correcto, ya habia cambiado el tipo porque en mysql pide primero el año, sin embargo no se porque a mi no me deja ejecutarlo desde la primer columna si ya revise que los datos sean correctos :(

Comment: "_sin embargo no se porque a mi no me deja ejecutarlo desde la primer columna_", ¿a qué te refieres con esto?

Comment: pues a que me sale el error en Id_registro en el renglon 1